# JMS Listener fires before Hibernate is setup on Server startup

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, jms, spring-jms

I have a grails 2.2 application that uses the JMS plugin (using version 1.3).

The situation I have is that when my server starts up, the JMS plugin initialises and the Listener service grabs any waiting messages on the queue before the server has completed setting up.

Specifically, it hits the first hibernate query in the code and fails with the following error:

```
| Error 2014-10-14 11:06:56,535 [ruleInputDataListenerJmsListenerContainer-1] ERROR drms.RuleInputDataListenerService  - Message Exception: Failed to process JMS Message.
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: au.edu.csu.drms.Field.executeQuery() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: executeQuery(java.lang.String), executeQuery(java.lang.String, java.util.Collection), executeQuery(java.lang.String, java.util.Map), executeQuery(java.lang.String, java.util.Collection, java.util.Map), executeQuery(java.lang.String, java.util.Map, java.util.Map)
```

The code in question is correct:

```
String query = "SELECT f FROM field f WHERE (attributeName = :attributeName AND entityName = :entityName)"
def fieldList = Field.executeQuery(query, [attributeName: _attributeName, entityName: _entityName])
```

From what I can tell, it's a matter of hibernate not being initialised when the JMS listener executes the `onMessage` method. It also happens with a `withCriteria` or any other hibernate query method.

It only happens when there are messages on the queue on server start-up and fails for each message waiting. Once the queue is completed and it processes new messages, it works fine.

Is there a way to either get hibernate to initialise in time or to delay the Listener service from execute (much like the Quartz plugin that has a start up delay timer)?

**Update:**

I don't use a bean configuration because it's a daemon type application - we have no beans to define.

Is there a way to use @DependsOn and have my listener depend on Hibernate itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `@DependsOn` notation didn't work due to the nature of my application (no bean configuration).

Given that there are a few bugs/problems with the Grails JMS plugin, the solution to my problem was to use the following code prior to processing the JMS Message:

```
def onMessage(msg) {
    try {
        Rule.withNewTransaction {
            log.info("Hibernate is up and running!")
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        resendMessage(msg)
    }

    // rest of code...
}
```

Where I use a transaction to test if Hibernate is fully initialised (already tested that it's not when the JMS listener fires at start up) and if it catches an exception, it will resend the message back to the queue for re-processing.

Comment: so now you create a new transaction on every message?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker, Yes, it would appear so.

Comment: Did it affect performance? There can be a lot of messages in JMS

Comment: Not this. Mostly we're finding shortcomings in the JMS plugin rather than db overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have the following EntityManagerFactory configuration:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect"/>
</bean>
```

You need to make your JMS connection factory depend on entityManagerFactory:

```
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory"
      destroy-method="stop" depends-on="jmsBroker, entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="activeMQConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: I don't have any bean configurations, as it's a service/daemon type app. Do you think the @dependsOn notation might work if I use a service instead?

Comment: It's worth giving it a try

Comment: Unfortunately, @DependsOn isn't helping. I used another service to depend on and it still fired before Hibernate was initialised.